# How to pass a hidden field value on javascript function inside repeater control

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I tried a lot but couldn't figure it out. I wanted to pass data on my javascript function.
I am saving data on hidden filed. what I want as soon I click on my button it will call javascript function & pass my hidden field vlaue.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptGallary" runat="server" >
   <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:HiddenField ID="hfsportsmanfeedid" runat="server" value='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"SportsmanFeedId") %>'/>
      <asp:Button ID="btnLike" runat="server" Text="Like" OnClientClick="Test("How to pass here"));" />
   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to pass the clicked element on `Test` button click

Try with this code:

**HTML/ASPX Markup**

```
<asp:Button ID="btnLike" runat="server" Text="Like" 
OnClientClick="Test(this);" />
```

**Javascript**

```
function Test(element){
  var $btn = $(element) // Gets clicked button
  var hiddenBValue = $btn.prev().val(); // Gets hidden element value
}
```

**Docs**

[prev()](https://api.jquery.com/prev/)

This should work!

Answer (score 0):

get the value of hidden field from repeater rptGallary_ItemCommand event and pass that to java script

```
protected void rptGallary_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        //add command name to btnLike button let it bet test here
        if (e.CommandName == "test")
        {
            HiddenField hiddenfield = (HiddenField)e.Item.Parent.Parent.FindControl("hfsportsmanfeedid");

            //pass that to javascript
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass it like,

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hfsportsmanfeedid" runat="server" value='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"SportsmanFeedId") %>'/>
<asp:Button ID="btnLike" runat="server" Text="Like" OnClientClick="Test('<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,\"SportsmanFeedId\") %>'));" />
```

**SCRIPT**

```
function Test(value){
   alert(value);
}
```

Or use [prev()](http://api.jquery.com/prev) like,

```
<asp:Button ID="btnLike" runat="server" Text="Like" OnClientClick="Test(this));" />
```

**SCRIPT**

```
function Test(ths){
   alert($(ths).prev().val());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this-

```
<asp:Button ID="btnLike" runat="server" Text="Like" OnClientClick="javascript:Test(document.getElementById('hfsportsmanfeedid').value);" />
```

Comment: It's repeater item template, you can't get same ID always!